# Adobe Edge - controlling an animation from the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I'm trying to integrate an Adobe Edge animation on one page of an HTML5 publication I'm preparing using a proprietary publishing system. The system displays different HTML pages like pages in a magazine.

I'd like to start playing the animation when the page containing it appears. Instead of an onLoad event, the publishing system triggers an onScreen event when the page is displayed. I know how to set a callback for that event, but I need the callback to start the animation. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I basically want to do the sort of thing we used to do with Flash, when we could send instructions to a SWF from a Javascript function in the HTML page that contains it.

Do I give the animation a name and then address it with something like document.animationName.play()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out. The AdobeEdge object will give you access to the timeline and the symbols you need.

The `getComposition()` function will let you access a specific composition. You pass it the name of your composition, which is in the properties panel and is usually a Edge generated ID like EDGE-344514744. You can rename it if you want to. Say you named it myAnim

`getStage()` gives you access to the stage and from there, you can use the methods like `play()`, `stop()`, etc. If you want to play a label you created in the timeline you've named "start" you could use this.

```
AdobeEdge.getComposition("myAnim").getStage().play("start");
```

Comment: I've not had a chance to test this out, but this looks a plausible solution to me, cheers planetoftheweb.